# Git remove tag with encoding error

Tags: git, tags

How to remove a tag with encoding error ?

```
git ls-remote --tags origin

7221ea1fa89c6c72f9cc402dd0c2778cbf6bf7d9        refs/tags/3.1_Bêta1
1466a61c89779bb3eb099d3f921e51bafbde6e7f        refs/tags/3.1_Bêta1^{}
```

i try to use :

```
git tag -d 3.1_Bêta1
error: tag '3.1_Bêta1' not found.

git tag -d 3.1_Bêta1^{}
error: tag '3.1_Bêta1{}' not found.

git push --delete origin 3.1_Bêta1
error: unable to delete '3.1_Bêta1': remote ref does not exist
```

I also try with the aplication Git Extension, the tag name display is "3.1_B�ta1", with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `git push origin :refs/tags/3.1_Bêta1`

Answer (score 0):

The tag names are not same as the original post. However, it is similar that I have had some unusual character in my tag (i.e. some square bracket).

I have resolved the problem using the below commands in **"Git Bash"**.

**Deleted the tag from local directory:-**

```
git tag -d /3.9.107
```

**Deleted the tag from remote:-**

```
git push origin :refs/tags//3.11
```

**Local windows folder:-**

I had a folder like this in windows. The last square bracket is displayed as '.' in window explorer. In git, the tag was "/3.9.107"

```
.git\refs\tags\
```